# Perform segue between xib and pass data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I've already found several answer to this question but no-one worked for my situation apart from one, but I'll talk about that later.

I'm using a particular Swift library which work only with cell created in file .xib. The view controller who contain this cell is situated in the main storyboard with the detail view controller..

My problem is that I can't perform segue programmatically when I click the cell and pass data to the detail controller.. 
If I use `performSegueWithIdentifier` it crash because it can't find the "segue" name.. Even if I ctrl+click from mainview(my Table view) to the detail. 
The only solution which works is this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerID") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem is that with this method I can't pass values and my app crash..

Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you say you can't pass values with this method? `vc` is your destination view controller.  If you use `as MyViewControllerSubclass` instead of `as UIViewController` you can access your subclass properties exactly as you would in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: I didn't think about it... I'll try it as soon as possible.. Thank you

Comment: you make my day! It works! Thank you @Paulw11